# redondear numero

Tags: javascript

Tengo un numero `X=302166.6666` y utilice la función:

```
 Math.trunc(302166.6666)
```

esto, para que el resultado me diera `302166`, pero ahora, como puedo dejar ese valor en `302170` en js

Answer (score 5):

> [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/round) 
>    retorna el valor de un número redondeado al entero más cercano.

Entonces en este caso lo que tienes que hacer es dividir por 10 para correr la coma 1 lugar a la izquierda, redondearlo y luego multiplicarlo por 10 para volver la coma a su lugar. Así:

```js
console.log(Math.round(302166.6666/10)*10);
```

Como bien apunta @SebasCarrillo en su respuesta, `302166.6666.toFixed(0)` resolvería también el problema. Pero habría que considerar algunas cuestiones:

`toFixed()` retorna un **string**. Si necesitamos hacer una operación con ese número y hacemos `302166.6666.toFixed(0) + 1`, **va a concatenarle el 1, no va a sumarlo**. Para solucionar esto tendríamos que hacer `+302166.6666.toFixed(0) + 1` o `parseInt(302166.6666.toFixed(0)) + 1` y si el `toFixed` nos queda del lado derecho `1 + (+302166.6666.toFixed(0))` o `parseInt()`. Por estas razones y los cuidados que hay que tener, no prefiero `toFixed()`, a menos que sea el último valor a retornar.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar divisiones y multiplicaciones para redondear a la cifra significativa que deseas. Nota que usamos `round` no `trunc` para redondear correctamente.
Por ejemplo, para redondear todos los decimales hasta la primera unidad, basta con hacer lo siguiente:

```
Math.round(302166.6666/10)*10
```

y te entregará `302170`.

Comment: Gracias, era justo lo que necesitaba, otra consulta, esa funcion me Math.round(VALOR/10)*10 siempre me entregara un entero?

Answer (score 0):

```
X=302166.6666
```

con `x.toFixed(2)` bastaria

EL numero 2 es el numero de decimales que quieres que aparezcan!!, saludos

Comment: si hago `X.toFixed(0)` redondea!